# Site for discussing (West End) Theatres

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm thinking of booking a trip to a theatre later in the year.  There are seats near the front available, but two adjacent seats are priced vastly differently.

I was wondering if there is a site on the network where it would be appropriate to ask about the internal layout of theatres to find out what might actually be "wrong" with the lower priced seat.

---

Based on a comment below, [I've also asked](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3226/is-asking-specifics-about-theatres-on-topic-on-travel)  specifically on Meta.Travel.SE to find out if it would be considered on topic there.

Comment: Well, nothing graduated or in beta, pretty sure of that, Two relevant proposals though, both still in definition: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85740/the-theatre and http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79823/architecture

Comment: Thanks - will go add a sample question :)

Comment: @Chenmunka I wasn't sure - it doesn't seem to be specifically on-topic over there, but it's not really ruled out either.

Comment: What about Movies & TV?

Comment: @Zizouz212 perhaps, though note I'm talking about a stage theatre, not a movie theatre

Comment: @JamesThorpe Just after a quick look, I haven't found anything that says you can't in meta or the tour. You could ask on meta before you do, I wouldn't be surprised if its on topic there.

Comment: @Zizouz212 no. Live theater seats have nothing to do with M&TV.

Comment: @Catija Oh well, just a suggestion as i didn't find anything against it.

Comment: @Catija Brilliant site - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We all appreciate SE's many sites with their rapidly-swelling ranks (well... one would hope, anyway) but there's not *always* going to be "a site for that".

There are many websites out there than will answer extremely specific questions like this one and have already done the work of organizing data from a variety of sources... for theater seats, that could include seating maps on various websites, photos of the space and/or the view, along with user reviews. Going to another site (like [seatplan.com](http://www.seatplan.com/)) is probably your best bet to answer your question and, honestly, knowing that seat E45 is great but E47 is rubbish probably isn't going to help many other people in the long run unless Travel turned into a version of that site somehow.